# htaccess: Rewrite - but keep site resources?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this is likely a question that is being asked often, I've searched for answers but couldn't come up with anything that answers my case. I'm assuming it's because I'm not figuring out the correct search terms, so I'm sorry If this is redundant... Thank you for your time!

I use .htaccess to rewrite my URLs to a more user friendly format. That's really all I want to do so if there's an entirely better way to do it, I'd be grateful to learn!

Anyway; I rewrite localhost/room/2 to index.php?p=room&id=2. That works like a charm.

```
RewriteRule ^room/([0-9]*)$ /index.php?p=room&id=$1 [L]
```

You can probably already tell my problem: I'm creating a virtual folder using room/room_number. So when I - for example - include a picture using an IMG-Tag, that src-Attribute is being rewritten as well to fit the working directory the server assumes to be in. Instead of requesting

```
localhost/img/image.jpg
```

It requests

```
localhost/room/img/image.jpg
```

which obviously isn't the right location. So my question is; How do I rewrite the URL to something nice and user friendly while *simoultaneously* re-REdirecting the page's resources to their original path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use paths relative to the root directory by prepending the paths with a **leading slash**:

```
<img src="/img/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: My god man, thanks a bunch! Gotta love - and at the same plant your palm firmly in one's own face - when fixes are this simple.

Answer (score 1):

Another (and fairly standard) solution to this problem is to add a RewriteCond so that the rule is never applied when a resource is requested that really exists.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^room/([0-9]*)$ /index.php?p=room&id=$1 [L]
```